# Apache renewal SSL certificate

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, csr, renewal

Sorry, I am new with this and need some help.

I had SSL certificate issued by positivessl.com. Now, it will expire and I need to renew it.

I don't have the old CSR file (used to generate ssl cert at first), but I have old private key.

So can I generate CSR file using old private key like (is this correct comand):

```
openssl req -new -key ssl/oldPrivateKey.key -out ssl/newCsr.csr
```

And then use new CSR file to renew SSL certificate, so I don't need to do any other changes to my apache conf files.

Is this correct way.

I don't want to interrupt connection to my site, so had to ask the question because didn't find good answers anywhere about renewal procedure.

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not re-use the old CSR - you'll have to create a new one.

Yes, your command is correct!
Generate the CSR with your old private key:

```
  openssl req -key old_private_key.key -new -out newCSR.csr
```

See also:

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

Comment: Sorry, but one question. On this way, with generating new csr from new key, will they generate new crt file for me which I need to replace with the one which I currently use on my server, or they will just extend the existing one.

Comment: They will always create a new one! You can get it from anybody, doesn't have to be from the  same company as the previous one.